# Clojure: column info of &form metadata

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

**Environment**

- OS: OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)
- GNU Emacs 24.5.1
- CIDER 0.14.0snapshot (package: 20160806.2354)
- [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
- [cider/cider-nrepl "0.14.0-SNAPSHOT"]

If I run this code

```
(defmacro foo []
  (println "column:" (-> &form meta :column)))

(defn bar []
(foo)
 (foo))

(foo)
 (foo)
```

print results of inside **bar** function are

```
column: 1
column: 2
```

however, print results of outside **bar** function are

```
column: 0
column: 1
```

I expected both results became same column number but didn't. 
Is this correct behavior? If so, please let me know the reason why column index is different inside and outside of a function.

**Additional Information**

The output results when using `lein repl` and `(require target-file)` are same, also the output when using `cider-jack-in` and `cider-load-buffer` are same. The problem has occurred when using `cider-jack-in` and `cider-eval-last-sexp`.

This behaviour is a bug of cider. I created an [issue](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1823) on cider github.

Comment: A shorter string to demonstrate the problem is `(foo)` vs `(do\n(foo))`

Comment: And I'm fairly sure this is a problem in n-repl, more debugging tomorrow.

Comment: If anyone can find the last version combination of Clojure and nrepl where this worked it would help in tracking the problem down